# How to config Google Earth proxy when using trojan?

Tags: proxy, google-earth, trojan

I'm using v2ray(trojan server) to connect to google, everything works fine on the brower, but when I open up Google Earth, it shows that

```
Google earth is unable to connect to the Internet and try launching the application again.
Error code: c000000c
```

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNIlB.png)
Seems like google earth isn't going through my local trojan client, so my question is how to tell Google Earth to connect the server through my proxy?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://wangbjun.site/2021/linux/proxychains.html), you can set up a process that takes controll of all network activities, like [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng)